# import csv into MySQL: starting from 0

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I try to import a csv file into MySQL. Here is the csv file:

```
id,name
1,Tom
```

I use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE citytest2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (id, name);`

After that, I do `select * from citytest2` but I get such a result:

```
id,name
0,name
1,Tom
```

Where does that `0 name` come from?

Comment: I think it is reading from first line. so it is considering 1st line also a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you  must ignore the first line
using IGNORE

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE  citytest    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```